# Idiomatic Kotlin way to sum numbers from stdin until a condition is met

Tags: kotlin

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to do this, avoiding the mutable variable and the loop:

```
fun sumOfBigDecimals() : BigDecimal{
    var sum = BigDecimal.ZERO
    while(true){
        when(val num = readBigDecimal()){
            null -> return sum
            else -> sum += num
        }
    }
}

fun readBigDecimal() = readLine()?.let { if(it.isNotEmpty()) BigDecimal(it) else null }
```

Any other suggestions to make the code more concise and readable are welcome as well!

Comment: your `readBigDecimal` can be simplified to: `fun readBigDecimal() = readLine()?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() /* and any other condition that should hold */ }?.let(::BigDecimal)`... no need to write `else null`...  the rest is already summarized by gidds :-)

Comment: wondering why my question was downvoted. Anyone willing to offer an explanation? This is my first (and so far, only) question on SO and I thought it is a valid one to ask.

Comment: I can only guess... you showed some code and asked a question, but didn't really make any effort to solve it yourself? The person who downvoted you may also never return back to read your comment or see any improvements of your question... I am sorry, that I haven't any better explanation for you...

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your feedback. Seems like it's not clear enough from my question that the code snippet above is my attempt to solve the problem - as a Kotlin developer with some experience, this was my solution, but I was not happy with it, and I mentioned in my question what aspects of my solution I found unsatisfactory.

Comment: Well, it was only a guess.. if I downvote I try to leave a comment so the question can either be improved or deleted.. (except it is of a very poor quality, then I don't waste more time for explaining then was obviously used to ask) .. don't take it personal.. Maybe this question would better fit stack exchange site "code review"..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first function is fine, but it's written in an imperative style.  This is one of those cases where a functional style can be much more concise:

```
fun sumOfBigDecimals()
    = generateSequence(::readBigDecimal).reduce{ a, b -> a + b }
```

Hopefully this is fairly self-explanatory, but just in case:

The library function [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) builds a sequence (a lazy list), calling the given function for each new element, stopping when it returns `null`.

There's no general `sum` method we can use.  ([`sumBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) assumes that each value fits within an `Int`, so it doesn't support the arbitrary precision of `BigDecimal`.)  But we can easily build it using the [`reduce()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) function to add up consecutive values until there's only one left.

A slight variation on that is:

```
    = generateSequence(::readBigDecimal).reduce(BigDecimal::plus)
```

This uses a reference to the existing [`BigDecimal.plus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/plus.html) method to do the addition, instead of a lambda.  It takes a couple more characters, but may be marginally more efficient, and you may (or may not!) think it conceptually simpler.

(Your `readBigDecimal()` function is certainly using Kotlin idioms; it's a bit complex, but I can't immediately see any improvements.)